# Testing react and redux with karma and mocha

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, karma-runner, redux

I've started working with React and Redux and I'd like to write tests for it using Karma with Mocha and PhantomJS2. I'm using the sources here as base: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/counter . I basically want to run the tests there in Karma using Phantom instead of using node and the "npm test".

I've set up and installed the required packages for karma:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "test:karma": "karma start",
},
"karma": "^0.13.21",
"karma-babel-preprocessor": "^6.0.1",
"karma-mocha": "^0.2.2",
"karma-phantomjs2-launcher": "^0.5.0",
"phantomjs2": "^2.2.0",
```

And I've tried to figure out how to build my karma.config.js but I don't seem to get my tests to run and this is where I need the help.

karma.config.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    process.env.PHANTOMJS_BIN = './node_modules/phantomjs2/lib/phantom/bin';
    config.set({
        basePath: './',
        frameworks: ['mocha'],
        plugins: [ 'karma-mocha',  'karma-phantomjs2-launcher', 'karma-babel-preprocessor' ],
        files: [
            "components/Counter.js",
            "test/components/Counter.spec.js"
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            "components/Counter.js": ["babel"],
            "test/components/Counter.spec.js": ["babel"]
        },
        babelPreprocessor: {
            options: {
                "presets": ["es2015", "react"],
            }
        },
        reporters: ['progress'],
        browsers: ['PhantomJS2'],
        port: 9099,
        runnerPort: 9100,
        urlRoot: '/',
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: false,
        concurrency: Infinity
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/tree/v3.0.0), we have that exact setup – take a look at our [karma.conf.js](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/blob/v3.0.0/internals/testing/karma.conf.js) and the [PR](https://github.com/mxstbr/react-boilerplate/pull/117) that implemented Karma and let me know if that helps!